# Error when I'm trying to use angr on OS X

Tags: python, macos-high-sierra, angr

When I try to use `angr` I get this warning

> import angr WARNING | 2018-06-30 15:10:26,560 |
>   angr.state_plugins.unicorn_engine | failed loading
>   "angr_native.dylib", unicorn support disabled
>   (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/angr/lib/angr_native.dylib,
>   6): Library not loaded: libunicorn.1.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/angr/lib/angr_native.dylib
>   Reason: image not found:
>   dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/angr/lib/angr_native.dylib,
>   6): Library not loaded: libunicorn.1.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/angr/lib/angr_native.dylib
>   Reason: image not found)

Could you help to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have `libunicorn.1.dylib` on your computer? What's its full path? Try Finder's search or in the worst case the slow brute-force `find / -name 'libunicorn.*' 2>/dev/null` or the

Comment: Yes, it's on my computer.    
`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/unicorn/lib/libunicorn.a`
`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/unicorn/lib/libunicorn.dylib`
`/Users/cutlass/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/unicorn/lib/libunicorn.a`
`/Users/cutlass/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/unicorn/lib/libunicorn.dylib`
What should I do next?

Comment: having exactly the same issue.

Comment: Not sure how this applies on MacOS but on many Linux-based platforms, having `libfoo.so` but not `libfoo.`*version*`.so` is solved by installing the corresponding `-dev` package (i.e. you have used Apt or Yum to install `foo` but you still need `foo-dev` or `foo-devel`, respectively). As a distant hackish fallback, you can create the missing symlink yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got exactly the same issue. It was a shame on me that I did not follow the installation instruction https://docs.angr.io/INSTALL.html. On Mac, the following fix must be done.

```
BASEDIR=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
# If you don't know where your site-packages folder is, use this to find them:
python2 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"

install_name_tool -change libunicorn.1.dylib "$BASEDIR"/unicorn/lib/libunicorn.dylib "$BASEDIR"/angr/lib/angr_native.dylib
install_name_tool -change libpyvex.dylib "$BASEDIR"/pyvex/lib/libpyvex.dylib "$BASEDIR"/angr/lib/angr_native.dylib
```

Comment: I've tried it before, but after reading your advice, I've decided to follow installation instruction again. I thought there would be some dependency conflicts, so I followed the installation instruction again in a clean virtual environment, and it worked. It's a shame to me, too. Thank you for your advice.